# Starting with Tkinter for python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The sample:

```
# gui.py

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

Results in:

```
$ python gui.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 3, in <module>
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1814, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I'm running python 2.7.10 under cygwin.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I simply cannot understand why this question was down-voted.

Comment: @nbro If I have to guess I'd say it's because of a seeming lack of research effort. Googling the error message shows an x-server as the cause pretty quickly.

Comment: @runDOSrun In my opinion, unless a problem is pretty common, this kind "lack of research" you are talking about does not deserve down-votes, but we should instead warn the OP, but this is my opinion as I said.

Comment: @nbro: probably because it shows no effort to debug the problem yourself. If you search for the phrase "no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable" on this very site, you get 162 questions and 136 answers as of the day I post this comment.

Comment: @nbro: If you hover over the downvote button you can read *This question does not show any research effort*. But this has been discussed on meta often enough. There are actually multiple duplicates to this question. I'd consider that "common" enough.

Comment: There are indeed a lot of search results for "no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable", but all of them have a different set of variables than my case (cygwin+python+tkinter), so I couldn't infer any useful information from them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to install an X server as TCL now requires it.

This [mailing list post](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00435.html) mentions it:

> You need to install X, define the DISPLAY environment variable, and
>   start X.  After these steps, your Tkinter program should work again.